# SQL select if a certian number of WHERE clauses satisfied

Tags: sql, where-clause, netezza

So I have a SQL statement of the following form with multiple WHERE clauses:

```
SELECT cols FROM table
WHERE
CONDITION1 OR
CONDITION2 OR 
...
CONDITIONN
```

I know that if I run this, then I will get all rows that satisfy at least one of the above *n* conditions.

But now, I want to return the rows such that at least *k* of the WHERE conditions are satisfied. Is there a way to do this in SQL without writing out all *n* **Choose** *k* subsets of the set of WHERE clauses?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) are you using?

Comment: netezza sql....

Answer (score 3):

This is a rather tedious way, but it should work:

```
SELECT cols 
FROM table
WHERE 
    CASE WHEN CONDITION1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN CONDITION2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
    CASE WHEN CONDITION3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    ...
    >= N
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cols 
FROM table
WHERE 
 CASE status
   CASE WHEN CONDITION1 THEN 1
   CASE WHEN CONDITION2 THEN 1
END
```

http://a2znotes.blogspot.in/2012/12/control-flow-functions.html is a very good resource on MySQL if else, case statement. All are explained with examples.